# Selection Sortings

Tags: java, selection

The problem is when the Data is sort it doubles like:

Data : 20, 5, 9, 8, 7

The Output is :

```
  20, 5, 9, 8, 7
  5, 20, 9, 8 ,7
  5, 20, 9, 8 ,7
  5, 20, 9, 8 ,7
  5, 20, 9, 8 ,7
  5, 9, 20, 8 ,7
  5, 8, 20, 9 ,7
  5, 7, 20, 8 ,7
  5, 7, 9, 20 ,7
  5, 7, 8, 20 ,7
  5, 7, 8, 9 ,20
```

The   5, 20, 9, 8 ,7 part is being repeated 4 times, how can i remove it ?

```
for(i=0; i<r; i++)
{
  System.out.print(data[i]+"\t");
}
  System.out.print("\n");
  for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    smallest=i;
    for(j=i+1; j<size; j++)
    {
        if(data[i] > data[j] )
        {
            temp = data[j];
            data[j] = data[smallest];
            data[smallest] = temp;
        }

            for(k=0; k<size; k++)
            System.out.print(data[k]+"\t");
            System.out.print("\n");
         }

    }
```

Comment: Please post enough code for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Put your for loop that prints array inside `if(data[i] > data[j] )`

Comment: I'd guess its trying to figure out if 5 is less than 9, 8 and 7. What output do you want?

Answer (score 0):

The 5 20 9 8 7 is occurring because once you have placed the 5 in spot 0, it doe not need to be swapped anymore. The 5 is the smallest item in the array, so it just needs to check the other elements in the array to ensure that. The only way to remove those iterations is to change the sort method

Answer (score 0):

Error code Show data: **U remove loop for k without loop for j**

```
for(i=0; i<r; i++)
{
  System.out.print(data[i]+"\t");
}
  System.out.print("\n");
  for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    smallest=i;
    for(j=i+1; j<size; j++)
    {
        if(data[i] > data[j] )
        {
            temp = data[j];
            data[j] = data[smallest];
            data[smallest] = temp;
        }
   }
   for(k=0; k<size; k++)
   {
         System.out.print(data[k]+"\t");
         System.out.print("\n");
   }
    }
```